# Sending emails automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, email, razor

I'm working on an **MVC .Net web application**. I have a database in which i have a table called Tasks, every task is associated to one user and every task has a delay. I want to **send emails automatically** to the user to whom the task is associated before two days (for example) from its expiration date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows Service to send email automatically.

Please refer below link

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article931-how-to-send-mail-automatically-for-every-five-minutes-using-csharp.aspx

You can set the timer for 2 days with your logic.

Comment: What if for every 30 days

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Windows Service application or a Console application that will be scheduled to run at regular intervals using the Windows Scheduler (for example once a day), it will query your database, extract the records matching the required criteria and, yeah, [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).

The reason I am saying this is because this task should not be done by your web application. It should be performed by a separate application. Recurring background tasks such as the one you need to perform is a no-no in a web application. The Haacked discussed why this is a very bad idea: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Little mock up example:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = user.Tasks.ExpirationDate.Subtract(today);
int dateDiff = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays);

if (dateDiff == 2)
{
     //Send Email
}
```

You could then place this in a `Services/Email` folder in your mvc app and create a separate console app to request the page everyday, therefore running the query, e.g:

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("YOUR PAGE");
        string response = new System.IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse()
            .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

You would use Windows Task Scheduler to run the console app every day which would start the console app > console app requests page > page checks expiration date on tasks > sends emails